# Change nodes between pipeline stages

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

In my pipeline, I am changing from my master to a slave node in one of my stages:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Install Deps...') {
      steps {
        echo 'Do something here'
      }
    }
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        echo 'Build stuff here...'
        stash includes: 'dist/**/*', name: 'builtSources'
        node('Protractor') {
          dir('/some-dir/deploy') {
            unstash 'builtSources'
          }
        }
      }
    }
    stage('Tests') {
      steps {
        parallel (
          "Chrome": {
            echo 'Chrome testing here...'
          }
        )
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can see from the console output on Jenkins it correctly says 'running on master' at the start of the first stage, and changes to 'running on Protractor' in my second stage. When the third 'Tests' stage starts, I dont see the node change back to master in the console output, is that expected behaviour?

Should stages run on the master unless explicitly told otherwise with a node() block?

Answer (score 8):

you have a nested node. This should be equivalent to:

```
node {
    //run stuff on any node
    node('agent'){
        //run stuff on agent; other node is still busy
    }
    //return to original node; no message since it is still open
}
//outside of all nodes
```

Comment: The OP has a Declarative pipeline, and this is an example for a Scripted pipeline.  ON the other hand, this does help me, because there's more info on Declarative than there is on Scripted, and I'm editing someone else's project's Jenkinsfile, so I can't switch it to Declarative.

Answer (score 4):

Here is example which works for me, also you can do it in parallel:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label "server1"
    }
    options {
        skipDefaultCheckout true
    }
    stages {      
        stage("Some stage 1"){
            steps{
                script {
                    echo "Hello world"
                }
            }
        }
        stage("Some stage 2") {
            agent {
                label 'server2'
            }
            steps{
                script {
                    echo "Hello world"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            deleteDir()
            cleanWs()                   
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is that if you want stages to run on a specific node/agent then you should specify it. If not then the node that the next stage runs on will be affected by things like the Usage setting for your nodes (i.e. 'Use this node as much as possible' or 'Only build jobs with labels...'). In my setup once execution switches from the master to an agent node it won't switch back unless all of the executors on the agent are in use and the master has an open executor. Sounds like your current setup is similar.